# File to import not found or unreadable [omega 4] Windows OS

Tags: theming

I have installed **omega 4** theme successfully with the help of this [link](https://drupal.org/node/2204227) on **Windows 7** machine. Working with the theme is awesome, however when I enabled the sub theme ohm, there I am getting issues. I have made a change to the following line in **ohm/sass/layouts/hero/hero.layout.scss**

```
.l-constrained {
  width: 95%;
```

to

```
.l-constrained {
  width: $desk;
```

`$desk is a variable declared in sass/variables/_grid.scss file.`

Afterwards I am getting following error.

> sass/layouts/hero/hero.layout.scss (Line 1 of sass/variables/**/*:
>   File to import not found or unreadable: ../../variables/_colors.scss

I can see there is slolution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005361/sass-import-error-in-rails-3-app-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-comp), buit don't know how to implement it in omega 4 config.rb file.

**Edit:**

This is the problem of gem sass-globbing on Windows. If you are using it on Windows version having this issue, than try following solution [sass-globbing does not support Windows 7](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing/issues/10). If it does not work, try the following alternative (not the best solution but it works). Add following line in **ohm/sass/layouts/hero/hero.layout.scss**

```
// Globbing from within sub-folders only works with relative paths.
@import "../../variables/colors";
@import "../../variables/grid";
@import "../../variables/legacy";
@import "../../variables/typography";
```

Comment: I was baffled by the same issue with my own Omega 4 custom layout and your method worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this by editing your Gemfile and changing:
gem 'sass-globbing'
to
gem 'sass-globbing', '1.1.0'

Then go back to terminal and type: 
bundle

All should be fixed